# Proving a matrix is diagonalizable given the characteristic polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices, characteristic-polynomial

If we are given a real symmetric 2x2 matrix how can we deduce that it is diagonalizable given that we know the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Real symmetric matrices are always diagonalizable.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I suspect that's what we're trying to prove

Comment: @HallaSurvivor A diagonalizable and a non-diagonalizable matrix can have the same characteristic polynomial. This cannot help to prove anything.

Comment: @user I agree - but I still suspect we're trying to prove real symmetric matrices are diagonalizable. Until OP clarifies, that seems like the most reasonable interpretation of the question to me

Comment: Hi everyone thank you for the responses. From my understanding, we know that the matrix is real and symmetric and are looking to prove that it is diagonalizable by examining the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit of a trick problem, but oh well. We know a $\text{2 x 2}$ matrix is diagonalizable if the eigenvalues are distinct, so it suffices to show a real symmetric $\text{2 x 2}$ matrix with repeated eigenvalues is already diagonal.  (I take for granted the standard quadratic form argument that eigenvalues are necessarily real.)

*We can assume WLOG that* $A$ *has 2 positive* eigenvalues. If this wasn't the case, then instead the argument would be on $A' := A + \delta I$ for large enough $\delta$ so $A' \succ 0$, and $A$ is diagonalizable *iff* $A'$ is.  (More simplistically, if we prove $A'$ has all off-diagonal components equal to zero then $A'-\delta I =A$ does too.)

Then in the case of repeated eigenvalues, examining the characteristic polynomial we can see:

$0\lt \lambda_1\cdot\lambda_2 = \lambda_1^2 =\det\big(A\big)=a_{1,1}\cdot a_{2,2} -a_{1,2}\cdot a_{2,1}= a_{1,1}\cdot a_{2,2}-a_{1,2}^2$
$0\lt \lambda_1+\lambda_2 = 2\cdot\lambda_1 = \text{trace}\big(A\big) = a_{1,1}+a_{2,2}$

but we also have
$ \lambda_1 =  \big(\lambda_1^2\big)^\frac{1}{2}=\big(a_{1,1}\cdot a_{2,2}-a_{1,2}^2\big)^\frac{1}{2} \leq \big(a_{1,1}\cdot a_{2,2}\big)^\frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{1}{2}\big(a_{1,1}+a_{2,2}\big) = \frac{1}{2}\big(2\lambda_1\big) = \lambda_1$

the first inequality follows because
$a_{1,1}\cdot a_{2,2}-a_{1,2}^2 \leq a_{1,1}\cdot a_{2,2}$
i.e. since we are working in reals we know $a_{1,2}^2\geq 0$.

Since this upper bound is met with equality, we see that repeated eigenvalues for a $\text{2 x 2}$ real symmetric matrix implies $0=a_{1,2}=a_{2,1}$ -- i.e.  the matrix is already diagonal.  (The second inequality is of course $\text{GM}\leq \text{AM}$ and since it is met with equality this also implies $a_{1,1}=a_{2,2}$, i.e. $A\propto I$.)